# wrap html special chars with SOH control character

Tags: php, html

I have seen a php function from discuz forum script. It wraps html special characters < " > & with control character SOH ,ie. chr(1). like below:

```
<?php
$pre = chr(1);
$end = chr(1);
$string = str_replace(array('&amp;', '&quot;', '&lt;', '&gt;'), array($pre.'&'.$end, $pre.'"'.$end, $pre.'<'.$end, $pre.'>'.$end), $string);
?>
```

what is the purpose and functioning of this action?
full function is as below:

```
<?php
function cutstr($string, $length, $dot = ' ...') {
    if(strlen($string) <= $length) {
        return $string;
    }

    $pre = chr(1);
    $end = chr(1);
    $string = str_replace(array('&amp;', '&quot;', '&lt;', '&gt;'), array($pre.'&'.$end, $pre.'"'.$end, $pre.'<'.$end, $pre.'>'.$end), $string);

    $strcut = '';
    if(strtolower(CHARSET) == 'utf-8') {

        $n = $tn = $noc = 0;
        while($n < strlen($string)) {

            $t = ord($string[$n]);
            if($t == 9 || $t == 10 || (32 <= $t && $t <= 126)) {
                $tn = 1; $n++; $noc++;
            } elseif(194 <= $t && $t <= 223) {
                $tn = 2; $n += 2; $noc += 2;
            } elseif(224 <= $t && $t <= 239) {
                $tn = 3; $n += 3; $noc += 2;
            } elseif(240 <= $t && $t <= 247) {
                $tn = 4; $n += 4; $noc += 2;
            } elseif(248 <= $t && $t <= 251) {
                $tn = 5; $n += 5; $noc += 2;
            } elseif($t == 252 || $t == 253) {
                $tn = 6; $n += 6; $noc += 2;
            } else {
                $n++;
            }

            if($noc >= $length) {
                break;
            }

        }
        if($noc > $length) {
            $n -= $tn;
        }

        $strcut = substr($string, 0, $n);

    } else {
        $_length = $length - 1;
        for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            if(ord($string[$i]) <= 127) {
                $strcut .= $string[$i];
            } else if($i < $_length) {
                $strcut .= $string[$i].$string[++$i];
            }
        }
    }

    $strcut = str_replace(array($pre.'&'.$end, $pre.'"'.$end, $pre.'<'.$end, $pre.'>'.$end), array('&amp;', '&quot;', '&lt;', '&gt;'), $strcut);

    $pos = strrpos($strcut, chr(1));
    if($pos !== false) {
        $strcut = substr($strcut,0,$pos);
    }
    return $strcut.$dot;
}
?>
```

Appreciate in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The code is trying to determine how many printing characters there are in the string, so it can abbreviate it to a certain length. So at the beginning it wants to replace all the HTML entities with their single-character equivalents, e.g. `&amp;` is replaced with `&`. And at the end it wants to put them back to their originals.

But if it just replaced `&amp;` with `&`, and at the end replaced `&` with `&amp;`, it would do the wrong thing if the original string contained any `&` that weren't part of `&amp;` (or one of the other entities that the first replacement processes). So it wraps all the replacements with SOH (the loop that determines the size ignores control characters). Then at the end, it only replaces the wrapped characters with their entities, so this will only undo the original replacements.